# Using ObRegisterCallbacks With C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, driver

So I am trying to use C# and the [ObRegisterCallbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-obregistercallbacks) function to get notified about any calls to `OpenProcess`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
internal static class Win32SelfProtection
{
    [DllImport("NtosKrnl.exe", SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = false)]
    private static extern uint ObRegisterCallbacks(IntPtr callbackRegistration, out IntPtr registrationHandle);

    [DllImport("NtosKrnl.exe", SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = false)]
    private static extern void ObUnRegisterCallbacks(IntPtr registrationHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool VirtualProtect(IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flNewProtect, out uint lpflOldProtect);

    private const uint OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE = 0x00000001;
    private const uint OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_DUPLICATE = 0x00000002;

    private const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 0x04;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION
    {
        internal ushort Version;
        internal ushort OperationRegistrationCount; // 1
        internal IntPtr Altitude;
        internal IntPtr RegistrationContext; // NULL, probably
        internal IntPtr OperationRegistration; // OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION*
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION
    {
        internal IntPtr ObjectType; // PsProcessType
        internal uint Operations; // OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE
        internal IntPtr PreOperation; // POB_PRE_OPERATION_CALLBACK
        internal IntPtr PostOperation; // POB_POST_OPERATION_CALLBACK
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal unsafe struct UNICODE_STRING
    {
        internal ushort Length;
        internal ushort MaximumLength;
        internal IntPtr Buffer;
    }

    internal static unsafe void Protect()
    {
        PobPreOperationCallback preOperationCallback = PreOperationCallback;
        IntPtr pPreOperationCallback = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(preOperationCallback);
        PobPostOperationCallback postOperationCallback = PostOperationCallback;
        IntPtr pPostOperationCallback = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(postOperationCallback);
        OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION operationRegistration = new OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION
        {
            ObjectType = IntPtr.Zero, // I have no idea ... <-- Need pointer to PsProcessType
            Operations = OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE,
            PreOperation = pPreOperationCallback,
            PostOperation = pPostOperationCallback
        };
        IntPtr pOperationRegistration = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(operationRegistration, pOperationRegistration, false);

        const ushort buffersize = sizeof(ushort) * 64;
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffersize);
        // No idea what kind of string I should put in here :C just zero it for now ...
        Marshal.Copy(new byte[buffersize], 0, buffer, buffersize);
        UNICODE_STRING unicodeString = new UNICODE_STRING
        {
            Length = buffersize,
            MaximumLength = buffersize,
            Buffer = buffer
        };
        IntPtr pUnicodeString = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(UNICODE_STRING));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(unicodeString, pUnicodeString, false);

        OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION callbackRegistration = new OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION
        {
            Version = 0x0100,
            OperationRegistrationCount = 1,
            Altitude = pUnicodeString,
            RegistrationContext = IntPtr.Zero,
            OperationRegistration = pOperationRegistration
        };
        IntPtr pCallbackRegistration = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(callbackRegistration, pCallbackRegistration, false);

        uint status = ObRegisterCallbacks(pCallbackRegistration, out IntPtr hRegistration); // FAILS WITH: AccessViolationException

        // yeah, yeah I'll remember to call Marshal.FreeHGlobal() later ... :D
    } 

    public delegate uint PobPreOperationCallback(IntPtr registrationContext, IntPtr operationInformation);

    // dummy method for now
    internal static uint PreOperationCallback(IntPtr registrationContext, IntPtr operationInformation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PreOperationCallback!");
        return 0x0;
    }

    
    public delegate void PobPostOperationCallback(IntPtr registrationContext, IntPtr operationInformation);

    // dummy method for now
    internal static void PostOperationCallback(IntPtr registrationContext, IntPtr operationInformation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PostOperationCallback!");
    }
}
```

The `ObRegisterCallbacks` function takes an `OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION` struct ([docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_ob_callback_registration)) as parameter that itself consists of an array of `OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION` structs ([docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_ob_operation_registration)).

This is where I'm stuck:
The [`OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_ob_operation_registration)'s first member, "ObjectType", is documented as follows

> `ObjectType`
>
> A pointer to the object type that triggers the callback routine. Specify one of the following values:
>
> - **PsProcessType** for process handle operations
> - **PsThreadType** for thread handle operations
> - **ExDesktopObjectType** for desktop handle operations. This value is supported in Windows 10 and not in the earlier versions of the operating system.

After a few hour of searching I still have no clue how I'm supposed to specify `PsProcessType` and initialize my struct with it. `PsProcessType` [seems to be defined in `process.c` in line 20](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d2/d9f/ntoskrnl_2ps_2process_8c.html#a5831e6e9cf425b592554e81508ce2155).
However it literally just says

```
POBJECT_TYPE PsProcessType = NULL;
```

which isn't especially helpful, since when setting the ObjectType field to `IntPtr.Zero` when initializing the `OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION` struct a `System.AccessViolationException` is triggered when calling `ObRegisterCallbacks`. (There's also a `UNICODE_STRING` in the `OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION` struct called `Altitude` that has to be set to some value (but currently isn't lol :D), but that string is initialized and allocated, so it *shouldn't* be responsible for the access violation... right?)

This is my first time diving this deep into Windows kernel stuff, so it would be nice if someone could help me out with this or point me to some hidden resources I didn't manage to dig up :)

There's an [article](https://revers.engineering/superseding-driver-altitude-checks-on-windows/) that uses `ObRegisterCallbacks` for similar things (in C++ though), however they don't really specify where they're getting `PsProcessType` from, or how it's defined. So there has to be documentation somewhere out there, if they can successfully use that "ObjectType" field, right?

Comment: you think .NET code can work in kernel mode ?!

Comment: Did you find a way to make this code work? I developed a C driver with KMDF but if i can do this with c# it would be better for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PsProcessType` is exported at ntoskrnl.exe and is the same as `ObRegisterCallbacks`, the difference between them is that one is an exported global variable and the other is an exported function.

In C, these global variables are declared in wdm.h:

```c
extern POBJECT_TYPE *CmKeyObjectType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *IoFileObjectType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *ExEventObjectType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *ExSemaphoreObjectType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *TmTransactionManagerObjectType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *TmResourceManagerObjectType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *TmEnlistmentObjectType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *TmTransactionObjectType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *PsProcessType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *PsThreadType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *PsJobType;
extern POBJECT_TYPE *SeTokenObjectType;
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_THRESHOLD)
extern POBJECT_TYPE *ExDesktopObjectType;
#endif
```

So you can just use these variables without having to do anything else.
But I'm not good at C#, and I'm not even sure if C# modules can be loaded into the kernel.

The most recommended approach is to use C/C++ for kernel programming, and I've never heard of anyone doing this with C#.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Up until this point I was pretty sure this could be done using C# (except maybe getting the managed callback methods to be called from native code). But turns out you can't use extern variables anyways. So I'll just have to put my code into a native dll and then somehow hook my C/C++ methods to managed C# methods. But that should be doable using DllImport :D

Comment: @FrederikHoeft - any c# code can not be loaded in kernel. no way.

Comment: @RbMm After taking a closer look at driver development today, you're absolutely right. Then again I wasn't trying to write a whole driver that has to be loaded into the kernel up until now ^^ I thought using `ObRegisterCallbacks` would be more like using any other "normal" P/Invoke call to the WinApi :D So yeah in this case I'll obviously use C/C++ for the driver and then do some Interop to my C# application. That should do the trick

Comment: @FrederikHoeft - any *.net* code (including *c#* ) require *mscoree.dll* - this dll can not be loaded to kernel as result and *.net* code too.